# WP File Manager - Cannot view PDF

Tags: wordpress

I am working for a client and cannot seem to find the solution to this issue. When changing the file path for the root directory of the WP File Manager we can "lockdown" and specify that we want the /home/site_name/files folder for the users to see when logged in. The default file path is /home/site_name/ and I can view the PDF's in the files folder by navigating and opening them up.

But once I specify that I want only the contents in the /home/site_name/file to be viewed I can no longer open the PDF's, it will give me a 404 this page cannot be found. If I take this URL and add in the /files/file_name then it loads... there is some disconnect between the link and the file path and I cannot figure it out.

Let me know if anyone has seen this before while using Wordpress File Manager!

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and consider revising your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After contacting the developers of the plugin there was a known issue with it, now with the new version the bug is fixed